# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager, The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am writing an asp.net console application, which reads values from .csv file and updates our database accordingly.
Inside this code, I am creating a new instance of Contact, based on its value inside the .csv file.
If the Contact table contains the same contact (contact with similar email), then update existing contact, but if the contact does not exist then create a new one. Here is my code:-

```
Contact contact = new Contact()
{
    RecordId = fields[RecordIdIndex],
    Salutation = fields[SalutationIndex],
    firstName = fields[FirstNameIndex],
    LastName = fields[LastNameIndex],
    Organization = fields[OrganizationIndex],
    Title = fields[TitleIndex],
    Phone = fields[PhoneIndex],
    Email = fields[EmailIndex],
    // Properties go here...
};

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email) && entities.Contacts.Any(a => a.Email.ToLower() == contact.Email.ToLower()))
{
    // Contact already exists. Remove old.
    var dbcontact = entities.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email.ToLower() == contact.Email.ToLower());
    int contactid = dbcontact.ID;
    dbcontact = contact;
    dbcontact.ID = contactid;
    entities.Entry(dbcontact).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
else 
{
    entities.Contacts.Add(contact);
}

entities.SaveChanges();
```

The `Contact.ID` is a database id, which does not exist inside the .csv file.
The above code will raise the following exception:-

> An object with the same key already exists in the
>   ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple
>   objects with the same key.

But I am not sure why this is happening. I only have 2 Contact objects, one with `ID=0` which represents the contact info inside the .csv file, while the other is the dbcontact. Is this correct?

Comment: Even when fixed, this may not be the most efficient way. Do you expect to update/insert many contacts per file?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `dbcontact = contact` doesn't change the tracked reference in `DbContext`.

Here's a clean way to handle both cases without code duplication:

```
private void Update(Contact contact, string[] fields)
{
    contact.RecordId = fields[RecordIdIndex];
    contact.Salutation = fields[SalutationIndex];
    contact.firstName = fields[FirstNameIndex];
    contact.LastName = fields[LastNameIndex];
    contact.Organization = fields[OrganizationIndex];
    contact.Title = fields[TitleIndex];
    contact.Phone = fields[PhoneIndex];
    contact.Email = fields[EmailIndex];
    // Properties go here...

    return contact;
};

public void CreateOrUpdate()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email) && entities.Contacts.Any(a => a.Email.ToLower() == contact.Email.ToLower()))
    {
        // Contact already exists
        var dbcontact = entities.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email.ToLower() == contact.Email.ToLower());
        Update(dbcontact, fields);
        entities.Entry(dbcontact).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else 
    {
        var contact = new Contact();
        Update(contact, fields);
        entities.Contacts.Add(contact);
    }

    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: so you mean the error i got is that when i do `dbcontact = contact` this will force both objects to have the same key ?

Comment: No. When you do `dbcontact = contact`, EF is still tracking the original `dbcontact`. When you do `entities.Entry(dbcontact).State = EntityState.Modified;`, EF now also tracks the new `contact` with same key.